# Relation between KKT necessary conditions

Tags: optimization, lagrangian

I am trying to understand the relationships in the KKT theorem between being a maximizer, satisfying the first order conditions (FOCs) and complementary slackness (CSC), and the linearly independent constraint qualification (LICQ). My understanding is given schematically by the following Venn diagram. Is this correct?
[image]

It would also be great to know how having a concave Lagrangian (which, along with the FOCs+CSC, gives a *sufficient* condition for a maximizer) fits in this diagram.

Any insight is appreciated!

Note: By FOCs, I mean the stationarity condition, and I include primal/dual feasibility conditions in my use of "CSC."